# Can I work on 2 simultaneous TFS task at the same visual studio solution?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS as a source code version control in my project.

I am working on a project where I get many task to work on everyday.Now the problem is to start working on second task I had to exclude the changes. Now once the first task is checked in than I can associate the second task and include the changes.

Is there any way I can associate multiple task and their changes in one solution?

Comment: Are you asking if you can associate more than one task with a changeset?

Comment: That I can do, I am asking about Isolating 2 different task and their changes.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear, I am pretty new to TFS. here is the problem, I am working on one task, associated the changes and until check in is not finish I have to wait for associating another task and their changes

Comment: Are you working on the same file for both tasks?

Comment: I am sometime but in that case I associate both the task at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have multiple workspaces whereby you can isolate the changes for one workitem from another.

The only way to achieve this is by using shelvesets and either committing these, or uploading to server without keeping the changes locally and then loading or creating another shelveset.

Comment: Thanks, we can suspend one and start working on another. I found a good Microsoft link for the same: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking entirely but I think your choices are:

1. Use shelvesets to keep change separate
2. Create a feature branch to keep things separate.

At some point you are likely going to want \ need to consolidate the changes into a single file.